# How to declare and instantiate a variable in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qpixmap

At first I want to apologize for this stupid question, but I'm fairly new to Qt, so forgive me ;)

I'm drawing `QPixmaps`. But for performance issues I only want to load my `QPixmaps` once to use them over and over again. At the moment I'm loading them always when update is called, but it should be possible to load them only once in the constructor. How would the `.h` file and the declaration of the `QPixmap` variables look in this case? Couldn't figure it out so far.

Comment: Can't you load them in the constructor of whatever widget they are drawn in?

Comment: You might want to read some introductory book on C++, the question is not as much Qt as it is basic C++ knowledge

Comment: @ Luc Touraille: thats exactly what I want to do, but what David Rodriguez mentioned correctly is, that I don't know the C++ basics. I thought maybe someone could help me out with a quick example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is a C++ library, so you just write c++ code:

Header:

```
class foo : public QWidget {
public:
    foo(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QPixMap *bar;
};
```

Source:

```
foo::foo(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    bar = new QPixMap("bar.png");
    // Some error checking...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But when Im compiling he throws me an error at this line in the update() call: painter.drawPixmap(0,0, myPixmap);
He says: "No matching function for call to 'QPainter::drawPixmap"

Comment: Please post the entire error message, I think the problem might be that your argument to drawPixmap has the wrong type.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'QPainter::drawPixmap(int, int, QPixmap**)'

Comment: Sorry, the error: no matching function for call to 'QPainter::drawPixmap(int, int, QPixmap**)' is thrown when I call painter.drawPixmap(0,0, &myPixmap); If I call painter.drawPixmap(0,0, myPixmap); it throws the error: no matching function for call to 'QPainter::drawPixmap(int, int, QPixmap*&)'

Comment: Worked when I called  painter.drawPixmap(0,0, *myPixmap); Next time Ill recall all the pointer stuff before writing in c++

Comment: The function siganture is void QPainter::drawPixmap int x, int y, const QPixmap& pixmap), so type painter.drawPixmap(0,0, *myPixmap).  Learn about pointers and references.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to optimize the image loading: if you load them by passing a filename parameter to the constructor of `QPixmap` or to `QPixmap::load`, they are automatically cached in `QPixmapCache` as mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html#load).

And if you really want to keep a `QPixmap` as a member in your class, you shouldn't use a pointer because, basically:

- the `QPixmap` objects are already smart pointers, like all Qt "implicitly shared types" from [that list](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/implicit-sharing.html#list-of-classes) and,
- raw pointers are evil, because, they can be invalid and they need to be deleted manually.